# I need a help for Responsivevoice

Tags: responsivevoice

this code :

responsiveVoice.speak('قلم','Arabic Male');

responsiveVoice.speak('قلم','Arabic Female');

not working without getting error

Comment: Voice picked: undefined

Comment: This is a problem with this plugin. It does not always play the selected voice. I believe that you would need to take the paid version of it in order for it to work. Also did you try this on Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

you have to set pitch and rate

```
responsiveVoice.speak("قلم", "Arabic Male", {
                                pitch: 1
                            }, {
                                rate: 1
                            });
```